# Get wrong border width on firefox

Tags: css

When I set border-width to 1px I am having 0.8, when I set 5px, I get 4.8, but that just in firefox.

On Google Chrome is just fine.

edit: my firefox version is 55.0.3

Do you know what is going on?
Thank you.

orange box with h1:

[image: orange box with h1]

computed values:

[image: computed]

css rules:

[image: css]

Comment: can you post a live example ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zad2n40r/

Comment: it shows 5px on my Firefox

Comment: you can get the most simple example here https://jsfiddle.net/zad2n40r/1/

Comment: Hugo what is your firefox version?

Comment: still 5px @jairhumberto

Comment: are you looking at computed tab on console?

Comment: Shows 5px on my FF 55.0.3.

Comment: It's also 5px here ( in FF 55.0.2 Mac). But why bother - at least with the displays/screens available today, 4.8px will always be rounded to 5px..

Comment: In my screen it is causing an strange effect. But I'll ignore it for now :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(To address some uncertainity in discussion, posting half-baked semi-answer.)

Your display has DPI factor 125%.

"CSS Pixel" represent virtual measure and maps to physical pixels accordingly. Browsers do their best to render what you expect, and in case of borders you most probably expect sharp edges and no blurry antialiasing, but for example for 100 × 1% relatively sized child blocks you'd expect them to fill the 100% wide parent, regardless how clunky those fractions would be. To fulfill such expectations browsers result to lots of rounding and adjustments "behind the scenes", so no wonder values could go a bit unpredictable in some cases.

Have you measured dimensions of the border in your screenshot? It is not `5` physical pixels, nor `4.8` (what should be blurry), but is is actually `6` physical pixels wide.

To be honest, I'd guess that the `computedStyle` and values in developer tools should really tell the "nice lies" of CSS pixels and the produced values does not makes much sense to me either; I hope someone will authoritatively tell whether it is a bug or not.

### Some testing:

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('p'), e => {
  e.innerHTML = ', computed:'
  + getComputedStyle(e)['border-top-width']
  + ', rect.height: '
  + e.getBoundingClientRect().height
})
```

```css
p {
  border-color: red;
  border-top-style: solid;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}

p::before {
  content: attr(style)
}
```

```html
<p style="border-width:1px">
<p style="border-width:2px">
<p style="border-width:3px">
<p style="border-width:4px">
<p style="border-width:5px">
<p style="border-width:6px">
<p style="border-width:7px">
```

### Some reading:

https://johnresig.com/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/

https://webplatform.github.io/docs/tutorials/understanding-css-units/#Final-thoughts

Comment: thank you. my win10 was doind that. It was setted to 125% of original resolution, I found that this is because, in high density screens, the windows does that to improve readabity, because the texts become too small in such resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

After checking your jsfiddle, which works fine, i suppose you most likely have zoomed out your browser.

Try <kbd>Ctrl+0</kbd> or from the menu go to View->Zoom->Reset

---

Computed tab screenshot
[image: FF 55.0.3 Console/Computed tab screenshot]

Comment: my firefox version is 55.0.3, is yours the same?

Comment: @jairhumberto yes. 55.0.3 here as well.

Comment: @jairhumberto make sure the ctrl+0 is done in the FF window and not in the console window.

Comment: yes it is on ff window. I even closed the console to make sure. This is very odd.

Comment: In Win 10, you also have a zoom at the OS-level, especially useful on a netbook with full HD screen (1920px wide). Fx will consider the viewport is 1280px and apply relevant MQ if it's at 150% for example (1920 / 1.5 = 1280). But I think it's unrelated to the question: Fx DevTools will just display result of calculation with no rounding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've searched a lot to solve this issue and your answer helped me