# Computed border width less than specified border width in div

Tags: html, css

My `html` code is as follows

```
<div class="one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam eius officiis pariatur, sit earum repudiandae porro iure architecto magni quod voluptatum? Voluptas minima iure, alias quaerat sapiente nam animi voluptatem!</div>
```

And `CSS` is as follows

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #5cff11;
}

.one {
    border: 5px black solid;
}
```

Since I am not using `border-box` value for `box-sizing`, the total width I should get should be 210px. But when I inspect it, I get the following box model for the `div`.

[image: Box Model]

As can be seen here, the width of the border is set to `4.8px` and not `5px` as specified in sheet.
Why is this so ? My browser is Firefox version 90.0.2 and 64 bit.
Thanks

Comment: Cannot reproduce it. With the same version of firefox

Comment: Mihai, actually in Chrome, I do get 5px width, but for some reason, in Firefox, I am getting 4.8px width. Why could it be so since I am using latest version of Firefox ?

Comment: Are you using zoom? In Chrome sometimes the zoom causes such discrepancies due to number rounding. Can you please try changing the zoom from -50% to 150%

Comment: I don't know. Like i said. I cannot reproduce it with the same ( latest ) version

Comment: I think this is a well know issue.  Check the following links.  [link1](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=3032739), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46105681/get-wrong-border-width-on-firefox) , <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394545/what-could-make-firefox-render-an-incorrect-border-width/17477508">link3 </a>