# 1px border width gets 0.666667px

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I'm surprised, that integer border width in pixel units can get rendered fractional (1px => 0.666667px). How can this be understood?

```js
for (d of [d1, d2, d3, d4]) d.innerHTML += 'px ' + getComputedStyle(d)["border-width"]
```

```html
<div id="d1" style="border: 1px solid">1</div>
<br>
<div id="d2" style="border: 2px solid">2</div>
<br>
<div id="d3" style="border: 3px solid">3</div>
<br>
<div id="d4" style="border: 4px solid">4</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fo156jxm

See also

- [Get wrong border width on firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46105681/get-wrong-border-width-on-firefox)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/37601899/11769765 (`window.devicePixelRatio`, for me 1.5 at 100% zoom and 2 at 133%).

Comment: When I run your snippet (and your fiddle), I see only whole numbers. What do you see, and on what browser on what operating system?

Comment: Firefox 106.0.5, right not with Chrome or Edge.

Answer (score 3):

It's page zooming. I can replicate that if I have the page zoomed (<kbd>Ctrl+=</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+-</kbd> on most browsers). If you set the page zoom to 100% (<kbd>Ctrl+0</kbd> on most browsers), you should see the numbers you expect.

Comment: Confirmed. Indeed, when zooming, one might expect something going. For Firefox the unexpected behaviour is observed even at 100% zoom; so maybe a bug or a different "feature".

Comment: @Friedrich - That's odd, for me Firefox doesn't do that at 100% zoom. As you say, some other feature...

Comment: I had in Firefox the jsFiddle at `zoom 130%` and saw fractions, after `[Ctrl-0]` and page refresh fractions were gone. Created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/qBKmoYX) with OP code, same effect. Running in Edge did not show fractions at all. Added `font-size: 15px; width: 250px` to all four and checked sizes. No effect, seems Firefox `border` specific. Can't think of a legit reason for Firefox to behave like that. @Friedrich